# DataSpell debugger often does not stop on breakpoints

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dataspell

The `Dataspell` debugger is flakey. Any hints on how to get some better results on breakpoints?  In the screenshot below we can see several breakpoints: none of them are respected.  I have cleared breakpoints, restarted the notebook etc. There does not seem to be a reliable way.

[image]

Comment: Any update on this whatsoever? Thanks!

Comment: I've just found - at least - that the debugger can't handle breakpoints from other cells (in all cases..?) so all code to be debugged must be within the same cell - or is this another intermittent issue?

Comment: @jtlz2 I was not even trying to do multiple cells, only single cell.  I gave up on `DataSpell` it was immature at that time and I rely on `PyCharm`

Comment: It's worth a revisit - it's coming on rapidly - but there's a serious turf war going on with vscode for stuff like this...

Comment: `vscode` is my lightweight editor of choice but `JetBrains` can not be supplanted as the king of IDE's in my world under any circumstances. I just love their keyboard customisations capabilities, local history, font/linesize tweaking.

`pycharm` does everything i need including an ok job with notebooks and good job with scikit learn / data science visualizations and even has v good `R` .  I'll probably stay there until/unless it gets broken permanently for some unforeseen reason

Comment: UPDATE: To put it bluntly, as of June 2023 it still sucks. Exactly as you describe!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with File/repair IDE and disabling windows defender.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).